# AWS/S3/Cloudfront/GoDadday and subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain, amazon-s3, godaddy, amazon-cloudfront

I am wondering and hoping this is possible.

On AWS I have two s3 buckets to separate a client facing application and an administrative application

1. mysite-app
2. mysite-admin

I have a cloudfront distribution for each application.

I have one AWS managed certificate for the following

1. *.mysite.app
2. mysite.app

So far everything works for `mysite-app`, and I am just adding the `admin` portion now.

To the question: will it be possible to have everything `*.mysite.app` go to my `mysite-app` *except*  `admin.mysite.app` goes to my `mysite-admin` distro?

Would I need separate certificates

1. `admin.mysite.app`
2. `*.mysite.app`/`mysite.app`

Would GoDaddy be able to support this?

Comment: What does CFA stand for? Suggest edit your question. I think you'd be better off with Route53 for this than GoDaddy DNS. GoDaddy domain registration is fine.

Comment: CFA = Client Facing Application. I'm stuck on GoDaddy for now.